# How can I capture a screen with a white background or a transparent screen with C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, screenshot, visual-studio-2022

I am developing a program that selects a certain range (adjusts the size) and captures it through Winforms. However, a transparent background or white color is recognized as transparent.

I searched for 'CopyFromScreen' on stackoverflow and found a similar phenomenon, but it did not show the same symptoms as mine.

I also tried 'BitBlt' of the Win32 API, but the result was the same.

Below is the code I wrote.

```
            capturePanel.Controls.Clear();
            this.TopMost = true;

            this.pictureBox = new PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox.Size = capturePanel.Size;
            this.pictureBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            this.pictureBox.BackColor = Color.White;
            capturePanel.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox);

            // capturePanel의 스크린 좌표 구하기
            Point screenPoint = capturePanel.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);

            // 스크린 캡처 로직
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(capturePanel.Width, capturePanel.Height);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp as Image))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(screenPoint.X, screenPoint.Y, 0, 0, capturePanel.Size);
            }

            // PictureBox에 완성된 이미지를 설정합니다.
            pictureBox.Image = bmp;
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'capture .. a transparent screen' - there's no transparent screen, every pixel has a color. You capture white pixels from the screen then set white as transparent `bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.White);` there are no 'transparent' pixels being captured

Comment: I tested it.
RGB 255,255,255 appears transparent
254,255,255 becomes a white background.

I want to fix the phenomenon where the part with a white background (255, 255, 255) is shown transparently when captured.

Comment: The call `bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.White);` tells the bitmap to treat color white (255, 255, 255) as transparent. If you don't want the bitmap to treat white as transparent, do not call that method on it.

Comment: _I tested it. RGB 255,255,255 appears transparent_ This is still unclear. RGB can't be transparent without the alpha channel and we don't know how you 'tested' it. - Also: anything you do before the capture get overwritten anyway.

Comment: set the line `bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.White);` to `bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.Purple);`  or any color you do not intend to use. in this context MakeTransparent just means ignore the colour white, but still take whatever is below the white areas.

Comment: Just delete the line `bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.White);` and you should see what you expect.

Comment: I modified the code in the question.

I create Form1.cs,
One panel was added. (name: capturePanel)
`Form1 - this.BackColor = Color.IndianRed;`
`Form1 - this.TransparencyKey = Color.Transparent;`
`capturePanel.BackColor = Color.White;`
After taking a screen capture
`this.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;` I modified it with
White color does not become transparent.

And when I capture again
`this.TransparencyKey = Color.Transparent;` Is it correct to do it again by modifying the properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to your question, how to make the entire form transparent.

You can use TransparencyKey, but you need to set the form's BackColor property to the same color as the TransparencyKey

Here is a sample code:

```
 this.BackColor = Color.Magenta;

 this.TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta;
```

The effect is as follows:

[image]

Comment: To be honest, I changed each attribute one by one for 3 days and did a lot of things, but I didn't think about having to match it with TransparencyKey. thank you